# How to change name of dummy variables?

Tags: linear-regression, stata, dummy-variable

I am creating dummy variables for out_of_order variable to run regression analysis using following command:

```
xi: asdoc regress score i.out_of_order, replace
```

I want to change the name of my dummy variables which is shown in the regression table.

[image: regression table]

Comment: Always use a screenshot as the image to embed in the post for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dummy variables are no different from any other variables so that `rename` is the way to change their names.

As documented at `help xi` you have scope through its `prefix()` option to change the names.

`xi` is mostly superseded by the use of factor variable notation from Stata 11 up. If you are using a Stata version older than the current version (16.1 as I write), it is a good idea to explain that.

I can't advise on any details to do with `asdoc`, which is community-contributed from SSC.

Screenshots are less helpful in general than results copied and pasted as code.